# StartService with argument

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

I am trying to convert a win32 application in to service. I use CreateService() to create it application as a service(using below code).

```
    SC_HANDLE schService = CreateService
    ( 
        schSCManager,   /* SCManager database      */ 
        pName,          /* name of service         */ 
        pName,          /* service name to display */ 
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        /* desired access          */ 
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS|SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS , /*service type*/ 
        SERVICE_AUTO_START,      /* start type              */ 
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      /* error control type      */ 
        pPath,          /* service's binary        */ 
        NULL,                      /* no load ordering group  */ 
        NULL,                      /* no tag identifier       */ 
        NULL,                      /* no dependencies         */ 
        NULL,                      /* LocalSystem account     */ 
        NULL
    );                     /* no password             */
```

I am able to start the service, if there is no argument in the actual application.  If i try to start the service with argument, then its creating problem.

```
LPCTSTR apszSvcArgv[32] = {"start","passwd"};
int nSvcArgc = 2;
if(StartService(schService, nSvcArgc,apszSvcArgv))
{
  return TRUE;
}
```

I tried to dump the incoming argument in the main program and its always showing the no of argument as 1.

Am i doing anything wrong?. Is it possible to pass argument like this to a win32 console application.

Please correct me if i am wrong.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just run a Console application as a service by calling the magic `CreateService` function. Windows Services are special types of applications, designed especially as services.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But i have some doubts, i am able create and start the service using the same if there is no argument. After creating, the service name is listing in services.msc and after starting, its coming properly in Task Manager. Evan i am able to access the service. I got this idean from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16488/A-Windows-Service-Application

Comment: Just because you are *able* to do something doesn't mean that it's a good idea or going to work. The `CreateService` function doesn't actually *validate* that your executable has been designed as a service, it just assumes that you know what you're doing. I don't know why you doubt what I just said, it's obvious that you're having problems making this work like you expect. The reason is because services are rather different from typical applications. Yes, there is wrong information on the Internet. The very first paragraph of the linked article evinces a critical misunderstanding of services.

Comment: thanks, Can u help me with some link,steps or sample by which i can convert my application as windows service. I am having a win32 console application written in C

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx

Answer (score 3):

you need to define the args vector as const char (or wchar), then pass the vector to StartService.

here is an example for a unicode program in VS

```
const wchar_t *args[] = { L"arg1", L"arg2", L"arg3", L"arg4" };
StartService(schService, 4, args);
```

Comment: my question is since the first parameter is always the service name, do you provide it at `StartService()` or does the system automatically add one, so in your example, the service would see 5 args?